# How to parcelize Google's Place class?

Tags: arraylist, kotlin, google-places-api, parcelable, parcel

in my custom object, i have 7 attributes, 5 of them are strings, and were auto genereated in the contructor fine, but the other two did not generate automatically. the last two are of class `Place` and `ArrayList<int>`:

```
class Spot() : Parcelable{
    private var uid: String? = null
    private var timeFrom: String? = null
    private var timeTo: String? = null
    private var rate: String? = null
    private var description: String? = null
    private var place: Place? = null
    private var days : ArrayList<Int>? = null

    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this() {
        uid = parcel.readString()
        timeFrom = parcel.readString()
        timeTo = parcel.readString()
        rate = parcel.readString()
        description = parcel.readString()
    }
...
```

How do i parcelize them?

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to do it. You need to add the code yourself for ArrayList and Place Object in the `constructor` and [writeToParcel](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/Parcelable.html#writetoparcel) methods.

**constructor**

```
constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this() {
        uid = parcel.readString()
        timeFrom = parcel.readString()
        timeTo = parcel.readString()
        rate = parcel.readString()
        description = parcel.readString()

        // Add the below to line of code
        days = parcel.readArrayList(Int::class.java.classLoader) as ArrayList<Int>?
        place = parcel.readParcelable<Place>(Place::class.java.classLoader)
    }
```

**writeToParcel**

```
override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(uid)
        parcel.writeString(timeFrom)
        parcel.writeString(timeTo)
        parcel.writeString(rate)
        parcel.writeString(description)

        // Add the below to line of code
        parcel.writeList(days)
        parcel.writeParcelable(place, flags)

    }
```

And if I'm not wrong, Googles Place class is already Parcelable so this code should work.

Hope it helps!

Comment: `.readParcelable<Place>` gives error: `Type argument is not within its bounds, Expected Parcelable!, Found Place`

Comment: which Place object are you using? It's saying the Place class is not Parcelable. I have used [this](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/model/Place) Google Place Object.